Implementing rate limiting for public endpoints in C# and .NET Core to mitigate brute force attacks
I need a way in C# / .NET Core app to limit the number of queries that can be made to a public endpoint within a certain amount of time. This is to prevent a brute force attack.
For example, a user makes a request to endpoint xx and it should allow only 3 requests, rejecting the fourth. How can I achieve this if it's a public endpoint where I cannot identify who is making the request?

You can achieve the rate limiting via the nuget AspNetCoreRateLimit by implementing a middleware service.
First you need to add the package into your project via :
dotnet add package AspNetCoreRateLimit

or use install this package via manage nuget packages UI interface in Visual Studio.
Secondly, update your appsettings.json file to use configuration like this:
{
  "IpRateLimiting": {
    "EnableEndpointRateLimiting": true,
    "StackBlockedRequests": false,
    "RealIpHeader": "X-Real-IP",
    "ClientIdHeader": "X-ClientId",
    "HttpStatusCode": 429,
    "GeneralRules": [
      {
        "Endpoint": "*:/api/publicendpoint",
        "Period": "1m",
        "Limit": 3
      }
    ]
  },
  "IpRateLimitPolicies": {
    "IpRules": []
  }
}

Thirdly, register rate limiting services in your Startup.cs or Program.cs like this:
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<IpRateLimitOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("IpRateLimiting")); // Load configurations added from appsettings.json
        services.Configure<IpRateLimitPolicies>(Configuration.GetSection("IpRateLimitPolicies"));              
        services.AddMemoryCache();   // Specify memory cache to store count limits            
        services.AddInMemoryRateLimiting();  // Add rate limiting services  
        services.AddMvc();          
        services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitConfiguration, RateLimitConfiguration>(); // Specify IpRateLimit middleware as single instance
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();    
        app.UseAuthorization();            

        app.UseIpRateLimiting(); // Enable IpRateLimiting middleware which we will implement in fourth stage    

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}

Fourthly, implement the middleware to limit the number of request like this:
public class RateLimitingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private static readonly MemoryCache _memoryCache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
    private static readonly TimeSpan _timeWindow = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    private static readonly int _maxRequests = 3;

    public RateLimitingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var ipAddress = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();

        if (IsRateLimited(ipAddress))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 429;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Too many requests. Please try again later.");
            return;
        }

        await _next(context);
    }

    private bool IsRateLimited(string ipAddress)
    {
        var cacheKey = $"RateLimit_{ipAddress}";

        if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out int requestCount))
        {
            if (requestCount >= _maxRequests)
            {
                return true;
            }

            _memoryCache.Set(cacheKey, ++requestCount, _timeWindow);
        }
        else
        {
            _memoryCache.Set(cacheKey, 1, _timeWindow);
        }

        return false;
    }
}

public static class RateLimitingMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseRateLimiting(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<RateLimitingMiddleware>();
    }
}

Now you can specify the and tell your application to use in your Startup.cs or Program.cs as shown here:
app.UseRateLimiting();


Can you explain why you prefer AspNetCoreRateLimit over the in-box Microsoft.AspNetCore.RateLimiting implementation?

@Dai I've been using this for 9 years now. Its has some highly configurable property set via appsettings with some rock solid documentation. Being said so using the inbuilt Microsoft.AspNetCore.RateLimiting will do the thing for OP question as well.

Can you check this question to see if you might know the answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78754133/net-8-concurrency-limiter-to-different-rpc-calls
